# Filtering Include values in Linq

Tags: .net, linq

With Linq, is there a way to consolidate these two lines into one method chain?

```
Group group = await _database.Groups.AsQueryable()
    .Include(g => g.Children)
    .Include(g => g.Documents)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(g => g.Pk == id);

group.Children = @group.Children.Where(c => c.Active).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

**Edit to explain structure:**

`group` is of type `Group`

the `Children` property on a `Group` is a `List<Group>`

Comment: Even if there was, I would not do it. Those two lines do different things. One is querying a data store, one is manipulating an object.

Comment: The point of doing this is to avoid the overhead of a potential large dataset that can be avoided by filtering invalid returned values.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the database do the filtering for you instead of bringing back all the children records:

```
var group = await _database.Groups.AsQueryable()
    .Where(g => g.Pk == id)
    .Select(g => new {
          Children = g.Children.Where(c => c.Active).ToList(),
          Documents = g.Documents.ToList() } )
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but it does negate the other properties on the Group data model and no longer grabs Children of Children, etc. (Children is a List<Group> on Group class)

Comment: You could include the other properties on the select